# codeigniter 3 Undefined property: Tabel_controller::$tabel_model

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, controller, undefined

my view

```html
       <table style="width: 978px"; class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nume</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Data inregistrare</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php
          if($user == false){
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Data masih kosong, silahkan isi dulu</div>
            <?php
          } else{
            $no = 1;
            foreach ($user as $row) {
          ?>
          <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->user_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->user_email; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->user_date_added; ?></td>
            <td class="text-center">
              <a href="<?php echo site_url('Tabel_controller/edit/'.$row->id) ?>" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
              <a href="<?php echo site_url('Tabel_controller/delete/'.$row->id) ?>" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php
            }
          }
          ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

my controller

```
public function delete(){
        $u = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->tabel_model->delete($u);
        redirect($this->index());
    }
```

my model

```
function delete($a){
        $this->db->delete('users', array('id' => $a));
        return;
    }   
}
```

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Tabel_controller::$tabel_model
>
> Filename: controllers/Tabel_controller.php
>
> Line Number: 59
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\application\controllers\Tabel_controller.php
>   Line: 59 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function delete() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\application\controllers\Tabel_controller.php on line
>   59 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function delete() on null
>
> Filename: controllers/Tabel_controller.php
>
> Line Number: 59
>
> Backtrace:

Comment: have you loaded your model in controller?

Comment: Load your model in construct area. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors